# Assign and use variables with the same condition without getting a warning

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I create and use a variable in Python (3.8) only under a certain condition without a linter warning?

For example, the following code triggers the warning `Local variable 'b' might be referenced before assignment` in my IDE (PyCharm):

```py
def my_function(n, condition):
  a = 1
  
  if condition:
    b = 2

  for _ in range(n):
    a += 1
    if condition:
       a += b

  return a
```

Setting `b = 0` and writing `a += 1 + b` is not possible for computational reasons.

Possible solutions which came to my mind are:

- Split this function into two separate functions which would lead to repeated code.
- Add an else case in which `b` is set to `None` which seems ugly in my opinion.

Comment: Why can't you set `b = 0` ?

Comment: it shouldn't give the error if you have the same `condition` variable at both places.

Comment: It seems you don't change the value of `b` anywhere, so you can simply do `a += 2` in the loop.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia they're not talking about executional error, it's PyCharm's warnings they're wanting to avoid.

Comment: what about doing 
`a += 1 if condition else 2` ? This way you get read of b altogether. (Note: I think this is what @Asocia suggests)

Comment: @Niels Thanks for your reply. In my actual code I use b at multiple occasions (everytime inside an if condition)

Comment: The warning is misleading, because as you wrote, you use the same condition. OTOH PyCharm helps you to write correct code. If you change one condition, you may get problems (and so it is considered bad style, although always correct). Just set b=None as else (so you get an error, when you change conditions, or just put conditional logic together (so b=0, and you add a and b together in the loop). Both make your code clearer and readable

Comment: @buesma then this is not a good [mre]. The obvious solution for the above is to remove `b`. If that is not an option, please provide a [mre] that reflects that

Comment: *Technically*, PyCharm is right that this code "might" access `b` without assigning to it. It would probably only do so if you specifically tried to make it do so, though, and making it do so is an interesting puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you even need `b`?

```
def my_function(n, condition):
    a = 1

    for _ in range(n):
        a += 1
        if condition:
            a += 2

    return a
```

---

If all you want is to avoid PyCharm's warning, please it by setting a default value for `b`. As I understand your code, it will not be used anyway, this is just to silence the warning:

```py
def my_function(n, condition):
    a = 1
    b = None
  
    if condition:
        b = 2

    [...]
```

---

Lastly, assuming you only access `b` under `if condition:` blocks, then there is no need to conditionally assign it in the first place. You can set it to the desired value, and you will only use it when needed:

```py
def my_function(n, condition):
    a = 1
    b = 2

    for _ in range(n):
        a += 1
        if condition:
           a += b
```

Comment: Is it better to set `b = None` or `b = 0`? In my opinion `b = None` clarifies that `b` is not used.

Comment: @buesma agreed. Changed accordingly. It is more likely to raise errors in case `b` was used somewhere not expected

Comment: @buesma i just rethought of your problem. I am guessing from your code that you only access `b` inside `if condition` blocks. If that is the case, you don't need a condition to assign it. Simply assign `b = 2` at the start of the function. You then only use it inside the condition anyway... Is that true?

Comment: This is right, that would be the best solution for the provided code example. As previously mentioned this example was not really fit to demonstrate my actual problem. Your solution above, however, has answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @buesma Happy to help! :) Anyway I updated the answer with that last conclusion

Answer (score 1):

You could create an increment variable which is either `1` or `3`:

```
def my_function(n, condition):
    if condition:
        increment = 3
    else:
        increment = 1

    a = 1

    for _ in range(n):
        a += increment
     
    return a
```